# Autocompletar formulário e verificar no JSON se existe

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer um formulário que funcione da seguinte maneira, o usuário deverá colocar seu CPF e o nome completo irá se autocompletar, e o formulário só poderá ser enviado caso esteja tudo ok no JSON.

Segue layout o modelo: 
[image: Layout]

Segue o código do meu formulário:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF:" value="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação inválida.
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomecomp" placeholder="Nome Completo:" value="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcao" placeholder="Função:" value="" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>



              <label for="genero" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Gênero</label>
              <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="genero" required="">
                  <label for="genero">Gênero</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Masculino</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="empresa" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Empresa</label>
              <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="empresa" required="">
                  <label for="empresa">empresa</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Empresa 1</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="regional" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Regional</label>
              <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="regional" required="">
                  <label for="regional">regional</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Regional 1</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="filial" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Filial</label>
              <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="filial" required="">
                  <label for="filial">regional</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Regional 1</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="hospedagem" class="col-sm-3 mb-4 col-form-label">Hospedagem</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="filial" required="">
                  <label for="filial">hospedagem</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Hospedagem 1</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>

              <label for="locomocao" class="col-sm-3 mb-4 col-form-label">Locomoção</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="locomocao" required="">
                  <label for="locomocao">locomocao</label>
                  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
                  <option>Locomoção 1</option>
                </select>

                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Informação obrigatória.
                </div>
              </div>



            </div>


            <hr class="mb-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Enviar</button></br>
            <small class="text-muted">Deseja cancelar o seu cadastro?</small>
          </form>
```

Estrutura do JSON:

```
"Funcionários": [
    {
        "cpf": "00000000000",
        "nome": "NOME COMPLETO"
    },
    {
        "cpf": "00000000000",
        "nome": "NOME COMPLETO"
    },
```

Comment: Oq quer dizer com "_caso esteja tudo ok no .JSON_"? Os dados não virão do JSON?

Comment: Sim sim, os dados virão do JSON, acho que expliquei errado essa parte, só irá enviar o formulário caso o CPF esteja no arquivo JSON, caso não esteja o mesmo não será enviado.

Comment: Como você pretende fazer o nome completo ser preenchido automaticamente?

Comment: Quando estiver digitando o **CPF**, quando o usuário clicar no **CPF** correto, o nome será preenchido automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com algumas funções você consegue completar o campo `#nome` de acordo com o CPF digitado e ao submeter o formulário, verificar se os dados estão corretos (veja comentários explicativos no código para entender).

Coloquei no JSON dois números hipotéticos de CPF para testar: `123` e `456`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var json = {"Funcionários": [
       {
           "cpf": "123",
           "nome": "NOME1"
       },
       {
           "cpf": "456",
           "nome": "NOME2"
       }
   ]};

   var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf");
   var nome = document.getElementById("nomecomp");
   
   // dispara ao submeter o formulário
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // só para exemplo. Exclua esta linha
      
      // verifica se o CPF existe e se os dados dos campos
      // são os mesmos do JSON
      if(buscaCpf(cpf.value, 1)){
         alert("Tudo certo!");
      }else{
         alert("CPF ou nome não existe no JSON");
      }
   }
   
   // pesquisa o CPF ao fazer blur no campo
   cpf.onblur = function(){
      buscaCpf(this.value);
   }
   
   function buscaCpf(CPF, validar){
      
      // busca o cpf no JSON
      var dados = json["Funcionários"].filter(
         function(e){ return e.cpf == CPF }
      );
      
      if(!validar){
         // se não for para validar, insere o nome caso tenha encontrado o CPF
         // se não encontrar, esvazia o campo "nome"
         nome.value = dados.length ? dados[0].nome : '';
   
      }else{
         // validação: retorna true apenas se o CPF e o NOME baterem com
         // o que estiver no JSON
         return dados.length && dados[0].nome == nome.value && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF:" value="" required="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação inválida.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomecomp" placeholder="Nome Completo:" value="" required="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcao" placeholder="Função:" value="" required="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>



  <label for="genero" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Gênero</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="genero" required="">
      <label for="genero">Gênero</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Masculino</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="empresa" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Empresa</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="empresa" required="">
      <label for="empresa">empresa</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Empresa 1</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="regional" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Regional</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="regional" required="">
      <label for="regional">regional</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Regional 1</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="filial" class="col-sm-2 mb-4 col-form-label">Filial</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="filial" required="">
      <label for="filial">regional</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Regional 1</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="hospedagem" class="col-sm-3 mb-4 col-form-label">Hospedagem</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="filial" required="">
      <label for="filial">hospedagem</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Hospedagem 1</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="locomocao" class="col-sm-3 mb-4 col-form-label">Locomoção</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="locomocao" required="">
      <label for="locomocao">locomocao</label>
      <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
      <option>Locomoção 1</option>
    </select>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Informação obrigatória.
    </div>
  </div>



</div>


<hr class="mb-4">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Enviar</button></br>
<small class="text-muted">Deseja cancelar o seu cadastro?</small>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou muito bem, nesse caso eu vou alterá-lo e colocar para que os demais itens sejam preenchidos. Agradeço muito pela sua atenção!

Comment: gostaria de acionar neste campo :  `return dados.length && dados[0].nome.value == nome  && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;` , funcao, regional, empresa e filial. 

Eu só copido e altero os valores ou tem alguma complementação?

Comment: É só acrescentar igual ao nome e cpf.

Comment: fiz, mas não obtive êxito @Sam

Comment: Primeiro vc tem que criar variáveis para cada campo, como fiz com o CPF e nome: `var nome = document.getElementById("nomecomp");`

Comment: depois acrescentar no return as verificações (não é criar vários returns como vc colocou abaixo)... inclusive remova lá pq ali é campo pra resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90723/discussion-between-sam-and-everton-gouveia).

Answer (score 1):

@Sam Fiz a adição como você citou mas quando clico no botão enviar, sempre aparece a mensagem: **CPF ou nome não existe no JSON**

Código modificado:

```
  // busca o cpf no JSON
          var dados = json["Funcionários"].filter(
             function(e){ return e.cpf == cpf }
          );

          if(!validar){
             // se não for para validar, insere o nome caso tenha encontrado o CPF
             // se não encontrar, esvazia o campo "nome"
             nome.value = dados.length ? dados[0].nome : '';
             funcao.value = dados.length ? dados[0].funcao : '';
             regional.value = dados.length ? dados[0].regional : '';
             empresa.value = dados.length ? dados[0].empresa : '';
             filial.value = dados.length ? dados[0].filial : '';


          }else{
             // validação: retorna true apenas se o CPF e o NOME baterem com
             // o que estiver no JSON
             return dados.length && dados[0].nome.value == nome && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;
             return dados.length && dados[0].funcao.value == funcao && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;
             return dados.length && dados[0].regional.value == regional && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;
             return dados.length && dados[0].empresa.value == empresa && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;
             return dados.length && dados[0].filial.value == filial && dados[0].cpf == cpf.value ? true : false;


          }
```

Comment: Não seria melhor tentar ajustar a minha resposta em vez de marcar a sua como correta? Eu perco 15pts e vc não ganha nada rs... Seria pra pelo menos valorizar o meu esforço.

Comment: Farei isso agora mesmo!, ainda sou um pouco perdido no stackoverflow...